# Failed to invoke public javafx.beans.property.LongProperty() with no args

Tags: java, json, javafx, gson

I have created a javaFx application with a RESTful service , I am trying to show the retrieved data to the javaFx application but I keep getting an error.

Alarm.java

```
public class Alarm implements Externalizable  {


    private final LongProperty id = new SimpleLongProperty();
    private final LongProperty floorNum = new SimpleLongProperty();
    private final LongProperty roomNum = new SimpleLongProperty();
    private final LongProperty smokeLevel = new SimpleLongProperty();
    private final LongProperty co2level = new SimpleLongProperty();

    public Alarm() {
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public LongProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public long getFloorNum() {
        return floorNum.get();
    }

    public LongProperty floorNumProperty() {
        return floorNum;
    }

    public void setFloorNum(long floorNum) {
        this.floorNum.set(floorNum);
    }

    public long getRoomNum() {
        return roomNum.get();
    }

    public LongProperty roomNumProperty() {
        return roomNum;
    }

    public void setRoomNum(long roomNum) {
        this.roomNum.set(roomNum);
    }

    public long getSmokeLevel() {
        return smokeLevel.get();
    }

    public LongProperty smokeLevelProperty() {
        return smokeLevel;
    }

    public void setSmokeLevel(long smokeLevel) {
        this.smokeLevel.set(smokeLevel);
    }

    public long getCo2level() {
        return co2level.get();
    }

    public LongProperty co2levelProperty() {
        return co2level;
    }

    public void setCo2level(long co2level) {
        this.co2level.set(co2level);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(getId());
        out.writeLong(getFloorNum());
        out.writeLong(getRoomNum());
        out.writeLong(getSmokeLevel());
        out.writeLong(getCo2level());
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        setId(in.readLong());
        setFloorNum(in.readLong());
        setRoomNum(in.readLong());
        setSmokeLevel(in.readLong());
        setCo2level(in.readLong());
    }
}
```

The method I use to retrieve the JSON data

```
public List<Alarm> getAlarms() throws RemoteException {
        ArrayList <Alarm> alarms = null;

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {

            //HTTP GET method
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/alarms");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

            // Create a custom response handler
            ResponseHandler < String > responseHandler = response -> {
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
            } else {
                throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
            }
            };
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseBody);

            //Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type alarmListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Alarm>>(){}.getType();
              alarms = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody,alarmListType);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return alarms;
    }
```

The error code I get

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public javafx.beans.property.LongProperty() with no args
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
    at rmiServer.serviceImpl.AlarmServiceImpl.getAlarms(AlarmServiceImpl.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAlarms(Unknown Source)
    at rmiClient.alarmForm.AlarmForm.setMain(AlarmForm.java:65)
    at rmiClient.client.Main.start(Main.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
    at rmiServer.serviceImpl.AlarmServiceImpl.getAlarms(AlarmServiceImpl.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application rmiClient.client.Main
```

I have created the javaFX application through an RMI server and client hence the file names, but according to my knowledge those files does not impact this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have two theories as to why this might not work.

1. Maybe gson cannot set Properties. Try using a long instead of a LongProperty.
2. As far as I know the fields in your Java code have to have the exact same name as the fields in the json you are trying to parse. Make sure that the names match.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see what's expected of a *complete* answer beyond general suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FxGson](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/fx-gson) to support javafx beans property.